# What are the available Java EE Websockets implementations?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket, java-ee-7, java-websocket

For the  JSR 356 - Java API for WebSocket i know the reference implementation is Tyrus.

Are there any others?

If not, then i guess Tyrus is the implementation in all Application Servers (Glassfish, JBossAS/Wildfly etc...)

Comment: AFAIK, [Tomcat](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/tree/trunk/java/org/apache/tomcat/websocket) and [Undertow](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/tree/master/websockets-jsr/src/main/java/io/undertow/websockets/jsr) provide a implementation for the JSR 356.

Comment: [Jetty](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/master/jetty-websocket) does the same.

Comment: And [Glassfish uses Tyrus](https://github.com/tyrus-project/tyrus), the reference implementation.

Comment: thanks a million! make sense for Tomcat & Undertow given they're mainly web containers/servers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there are a few [JSR 356 Java API for WebSocket](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=356) implementations besides [Tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net/) (the reference implementation):

- [Apache Tomcat](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/tree/trunk/java/org/apache/tomcat/websocket)
- [Jetty](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/master/jetty-websocket)
- [Undertow](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/tree/master/websockets-jsr/src/main/java/io/undertow/websockets/jsr) used by WildFly

Glassfish is the Java EE reference implementation and uses [Tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net/).

According to my researches:

- IBM [announced](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/blog/2014/12/09/announcing-new-liberty-features-tools/) WebSocket support for WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile 8.5.5, but there's no information about the implementation. Probably they are using their own solution.
- Oracle WebLogic Server introduced a proprietary WebSocket API in release 12.1.2 which is deprecated now, but remains supported for backward compatibility. According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLPRG/websockets.htm#WLPRG854), now the WebSocket protocol implementation in Oracle WebLogic Server is provided by the *reference implementation* of JSR 356 Java API for WebSocket.
- Other proprietary application servers might provide their own implementations.

Answer (score 0):

The Event Driven Framework supporting WebSocket and HTTP [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere)